# Tailing only updated line of file

Tags: unix, filesystems, hbase, tail, flume

I want to tail only the updated line of the file not entire content

tail -F /path to file

displays all the line from the file. I need to display only the new lines added to the file can anyone help me in this ?

for e.g.
i want to see only updated lines in the file for e.g if file has 10 lines tail -F shows me 10 lines on terminal now if 5 more line are added i should be able to see only new 5 lines not all the 15 lines

**EDIT**
I have configured flume to send the log data to hbase i am using "tail -F /path to file"
which gives me the all the lines everytime file is updated.Only updated log data(say 5 lines added) should be sent to hbase otherwise there will be data redundancy.

Regards Chhaya

Comment: You mean you only want to see the lines that were added since the last time you called `tail` on the file? You'll have to write your own script to keep a count of the lines, but it shouldn't be too hard. However, scripts with memory like that aren't really the UNIX way of doing things. The idea behind `tail -F` is that you keep it running (like on a log file) and get to see new lines as they are added.

Comment: "The idea behind tail -F is that you keep it running (like on a log file) and get to see new lines as they are added" 
i have kept tail running in one terminal then opened new terminal and modified the file , now i can see all the lines from the file along with new lines. i just want to see the new lines

Comment: i am putting this data in hbase so there will be repetition of data which is not the way i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that file is a log file?

So maybe, instead of trying to come up with a way to remember what was written the last time, and only display what's new, you probably want to use a logging system [like syslogd, or a newer version of it], and tell it to log both in the file AND send it to flume?

Otherwise, here is a dirty hack: create a "shownew.sh" file containing:

```
#try to be as "atomic" as possible: we will all do with a copy of ${1}, to "freeze" time
cp -p "${1}" "${1}.cur"  #very important. "freezes" the state of $1

if [ -f "${1}.old ]; then

   diff "${1}.old" "${1}.cur" | grep '^> ' | sed -e 's/^> //'

else

   cat "${1}.cur" #show the file at the time of invocation

fi

mv -f "${1}.cur" "${1}.old"  #we just showed "${1}.cur" (or the diff between ${1}.cur and a previous ${1}.old=.
  # so we now move that ${1}.cur $^{1}.old, for the next iteration
  #We used a ${1}.cur instead of ${1} because ${1} may be updated at any time, and it's possible we copy a "$1" updated since the display of differences! By using ${1}.cur instead, this won't be a problem

#edit: after the OP's comment he wants to tail -f the file too:
#and now we showed the diffs since $1.old, we continue to display what is new in $1, using tail -f:

#since we showed ${1}.cur (now known as ${1}.old}, $1 may have changed?
diff "${1}" "${1}.old" | grep '^> ' | sed -e 's/> //' 

#and now we tail -f on $1 to show what's incoming, until the user press ctrl+C
tail -n 0 -f "${1} 

#we showed the complete ${1}, this becomes the new ${1}.old
cp "${1}" "${1}.old"
```

- At the first invocation of, say, `shownew.sh  /some/file` : it displays it's whole content, if it's the first time you called it on `/some/file`.
- Each further time you call the script: `shownew.sh /some/file` :  it will only show lines that are now in "${1}" and that were not before in "${1}.old" ... I hope that's what you wanted ?

Comment: hey thanks u so much its working but i want to keep it running as Tail command does ? do not want to terminate

Comment: It's not easy to mix the above, which takes a "snapshot" of the file and then makes a diff, with a tail -f... I edited my answer to show you how to do that. Please try it

Answer (score 0):

If your log events are coming from a Java logging framework then I recommend using the Log4j2 Flume appender. That will ensure the latest events get to flume very quickly.